# Can't serialize using ObjectMapper Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Im getting an error while try use Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper

My function to call api

```
static func getUberIntegration(completion: @escaping ([Integrations]?) -> ()) {
        let url = "\(Url.baseURL())/integrations"
        let headers = Headers.authorization()

        Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Integrations]>)  in

          let integration = response.result.value
            print(integration!)

            completion(integration)

        }
    }
```

Model

```
class Integrations: Object, Mappable {

   @objc dynamic var id: Int32 = 0
   @objc dynamic var type: String = ""
   @objc dynamic var active: Bool = false

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        type <- map["type"]
        active <- map["active"]

    }


}
```

Response from API when status code 200 is

```
    {
    "id": 120,
    "type": "Integration",
    "active": true
    }
```

Anyone can explain why this issue is happening? When i print in debug status code is return code 200 but can't read json data

I get this error

> Error Domain=com.alamofireobjectmapper.error Code=2 "ObjectMapper
>   failed to serialize response."

Comment: You'r api response array of object or object ?

Comment: object only @a.masri

Comment: Ok , try to replace this `DataResponse<[Integrations]>` to `DataResponse<Integrations>`